# Kubernets Spark Operator: Configuring Automatic Application Restart and Failure Handling

Tags: kubernetes, spark-operator

On kubernetes a Container restart policy can be configured with an optional field `.spec.restartPolicy` which can be set to `type: OnFailure`. I read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy)
that there is a cap of 300 secs (5 mins) on an exponential back-off delay before a failed pod is restarted. My first confusion, does this cap of 300 secs apply to only the default configuration or does it affect for example, the below configuration. Also, I am wondering if increasing the number of retries for example `onFailureRetries:6` with an interval of `onFailureRetryInterval:9`  (considering the 300 sec cap) makes sense considering pressure on the resources on the cluster? Is there a resource available to help know which best configuration to use or will this be based on user experience, or I just have to try and see what makes sense for my cluster?

```
restartPolicy:
type: OnFailure
onFailureRetries: 3
onFailureRetryInterval: 10
onSubmissionFailureRetries: 5
onSubmissionFailureRetryInterval: 20
```

Comment: Could you please share your whole config (not only the `restartPolicy`) by editing the question?

Comment: Are you referring to Spark Application or Kubernetes Spark Operator?

Comment: I am talking about the Kubernetes Spark Operator